# Return specific results from array

Tags: php, arrays, itunes

I am trying to return iTunes store data, which I have managed to do successfully.

I found this: https://github.com/ijanerik/PHP-iTunes-API, which is great!

The only thing is I'm not sure of is how to print individual values.

For example my code looks like:

```
include("classes/itunes.php");

$albums = iTunes::lookup(304576306, 'id', array(
    'entity' => 'song'
))->results;

// var_dump($albums);
print_r($albums);
```

Which returns all the results: http://joshrodg.com/music/test/index.php.

How would I return just `trackName` or `artistName` from the array?

The example shows how to perform the lookup, just not how to get the individual data that gets returned.

I've tried a `foreach`, but maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
foreach($albums as $album):
    echo $album['trackName'];
    echo $album['artistName'];
endforeach;
```

Everytime I try that, the page whitescreens.

If I just try a `echo $album['trackName'];` or `echo $albums['trackName'];` the page also whitescreens.

So far the only way I have been able to return data is by using: `print_r($albums);` or `var_dump($albums);`

I know this is simple, just not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Learn what is object, and what's the difference between object and array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    foreach ($albums as $a) {
        if ($a->wrapperType == 'track') { 
            echo $a->trackName;
            echo $a->artistName;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: This one works nicely...still have to work on the formatting and everything, but now I can return the results I'm looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's returning the results as an object and not an array.  Try running through them like this:

```php
foreach($albums as $album):
{
    echo $album->trackName;
    echo $album->artistName;
}
```

Comment: Tried this one, just got a whitescreen.

Comment: You need to `display_errors` so that you can read the error message.  It's probably erring because one of those property names don't exist on all of the objects.  Waldson's answer works because he wrote in functionality to check for that.

Comment: I see that, both of them are the same except for the wrapperType...this will definitely help moving forward.